# How to fetch data from another database table in phtml file so that a pop up modal can be filled automatically?

Tags: database, modal-popup, data

I have created a model form and now want it to be pre-filled with data from the another database table.

Comment: try to share every detail you can to get the answers.

Comment: share the modal code, and from which table you want to fetch the data?

Comment: https://meetanshi.com/blog/display-table-data-magento-2/ this is the link followed and $collection is returning blank

Comment: 176 679 344  if you can access and solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use the controller ajax call or block function to get the data from your custom table and on run time use JS to fill the popup tags.